Boto3 Create connector profile in AWS App flow for salesforce
I'm trying to create a connector profile in AWS AppFlow using boto3's create_connector_profile for a Salesforce account. I'm using a Salesforce Developer Edition. I've created the connected app in Salesforce by following this blog. I'm using the create_connector_profile boto3 API to create the Salesforce connection. The connection is working fine, but after 24 hours, it's giving the error:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "expired access/refresh token"
}
I've also followed the AppFlow documentation for callback URLs documentation link. Can anyone suggest any settings I need to check, or any leads are appreciated? Thanks in advance.
I have tried to change some settings in the salesforce like session settings and I have changed the call back url's. but all the things are not worked. But when I try to create the connection from AWS App flow console the token which are generated in app flow are long living.
